# ffmpeg doesnt split file correctly

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm not sure if here is the right place to post this but here goes.

I use ffmpeg (ubuntu v3.2.7) to record live streaming from rstp camera using this command.

`ffmpeg -stimeout 600 -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://192.168.2.183/unicast -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 3600 -segment_wrap 100 -segment_format mov -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "/mnt/CCTV/XiaoFang/Bedroom/Capture-%Y-m-%d_%H-%M.mp4"`

Everything works great, until there will be a time it will continously record with the same file like this [image: Error]

Any idea on why this happens? Or a workaround for it?

If I try to play this video, it will only play the first few hours and the last few hours.

---

#### EDIT:

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ 1 ] ; do

ffmpeg -stimeout 600 -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://192.168.2.183/unicast -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 5 -segment_wrap 100 -segment_format mov -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "/mnt/CCTV/XiaoFang/Bedroom/Capture-%Y-m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"

if [ -e "abort" ] ; then

    rm "abort"

    break

fi

done
```

EDIT2: Unfortunately this still sometimes make it a big file. Still trying to find a workaround.

Comment: What do you mean by “there will be a time it will continuously record with the same file”?

Comment: If you see the error image, you will see the capture hour continue to record from 13-32 to 03-47. And the file is 13GB, which is about 15hrs of recording.

And then it continued to record as per normal again (probably because of the checker file I placed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this as a workaround:

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ 1 ] ; do
    ffmpeg ... (only record for one hour)
done
```

Each file will only be an hour long.  After the `ffmpeg` command, you could optionally put this code in to stop the recording once the current `ffmpeg` iteration finishes:

```
if [ -e "abort" ] ; then
    rm "abort"
    break
fi
```

Comment: So my command would be

> #!/bin/sh

while [ 1 ] ; do
ffmpeg -stimeout 600 -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://192.168.2.183/unicast -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 3600 -segment_wrap 100 -segment_format mov -reset_timestamps 1 -strftime 1 "/mnt/CCTV/XiaoFang/Bedroom/Capture-%Y-m-%d_%H-%M.mp4"
done

Comment: test it with: `-segment_time 5` just to see if it works. Also, add `%S` to the file name.

Comment: I edited my ffmpeg.sh with the code edited on my original post. The code means if I put -segment-time 3600, it will record for 1 hour, and the "if code" will break the recording and re-record on loop?

Comment: 1 day running, havent got a clogged file. Thanks for the workaround! Will post if anything goes wrong.